# "which is"-ing a clause in German

Tags: english-to-german, subordinate-clause

I often got doubts when I want to formulate a German sentence with a kind of "which is" that expands a clause, like in English. For example (not sure if this makes sense though):

> My grandparents both died at the age of 80, which is already a pretty
> good deal for Indonesians.

I usually do a literal verbatim transformation with "welche ist":

> Meine beiden Großeltern starben im Alter von 80 Jahren, welche für
> Indonesier schon ziemlich viel ist.

...but I'm not sure if this is the way to go in German. Is this "which is"-ing a thing in German? Or should I separate them into two sentences?

> Meine beiden Großeltern starben im Alter von 80 Jahren. Es ist schon ziemlich viel für Indonesier.

Comment: _a pretty good deal_ that a tad too idiomatic.

Comment: Das Geschlecht stimmt nicht. "Meine Eltern aßen eine Schwarzwälderkirschtorte, welche für Indonesier recht exotisch ist" - die Torte, hier würde es stimmen. Das Alter, dagegen, erfordert "... welches für Indonesier...".

Answer (score 25):

I'm quite sceptic concerning the value of too strict translations. I would write:

> Meine Großeltern starben beide mit 80 Jahren, was für Indonesier ein ziemlich hohes Alter ist.

*Ziemlich viel* is just too generic, it is not entirely clear, that it relates to the given age (as opposed to emotional stress for the survivors). It would fit, if the reference obviously refers to the number of years, but in the example it is the age instead. For *Alter* there is no really idiomatic alternative to *hoch*, leaving aside adjectives with a religious touch as *gesegnet* (blessed), *biblisch* (biblical).

Update: Further alternatives  like *fortgeschritten* and *ehrwürdig* exist, but are more formal and can be used for age only, but not for other measurement values like weight, temperature, speed, which *hoch* covers.

The separation in two sentences is not required, since it is not much information to convey. A semicolon would be a fine intermediate solution.

Comment: I beg to differ, how about _fortgeschritten_, _ehrwürdig_, _beträchtlich_ or _stolz_?

Comment: Or _beachtlich_

Comment: or you can use "krasses Alter" if you are talking between tweens ;-)

Answer (score 14):

Instead of "welche ist", you need to translate it with "was ... ist". E. g. your sentence would translate to

> Meine beiden Großeltern starben im Alter von 80 Jahren, was für Indonesier schon ziemlich viel ist.

I think you can always go with that, I can't think of any counter examples right now

Comment: I'd also mention "das .. ist" as an alternative to default to.

Comment: *Das* is not equivalent to *was* because *was* refers to the preceding sentence, wereas *das* refers to the preceding noun clause.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the reason for *was* instead of *welche*. I gather that the main difference is that using *welche* as a relative pronoun sounds pretentious and formal. Also, I think if you do use *welche*, it's still a relative clause so *ist* would be at the end.

Comment: it would have to be *welches*, since *Alter* is neutrum; and then it would sound neither pretentious nor formal, just odd to the ear of a native speaker, because it is simply the wrong choice of pronoun. The correct construction shown here and in Guidot's answer, as so often, shows that literal translations mostly don't work, and often learners will need to memorize constructions like this until they come naturally.

Comment: @dlatikay --Yes it would be *welches* in this case, but I was referring to any inflection. So the issue remains, for what reason is welche(r/s) not usable here? I'm getting my information from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/welcher#Usage_notes), are you saying it's incorrect?

Comment: @RDBury welches is "correct", but it sounds extremely unnatural. For one, it is basically never used (as Wiktionary says). But even when replaced with _das_, it sounds very unnatural. I think that is down to the difference RHa mentioned.

Comment: @jazzpi: I beg to disagree, I tend to think that *welches* is so unnatural that I'd say it is not the correct translation. Similar to a subordinate clause ", das ... ist" and as opposed to the 2 sentence construction ". Das ist ..."

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX It is grammatically correct. _welches_/_das_ in that case refers to _Alter von 80 Jahren_. Cf. "Dort steht ein Haus, das gelb ist."

Comment: @jazzpi: to me that's a quite different construction. But I'm no linguist.

Comment: The subordinated clause doesn't refer to _Alter_. It refers to the fact they died at 80. Therefore _"welches"_ is not the correct reference. One could similarly say: _Sie starben mit 80, was ... viel ist._

Comment: in this case, I would use "alt": "was für Indonesier schon ziemlich alt ist". Not a linguist so can't really explain why, but to my native speaker brain "viel" sounds weird/wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Both *was* (with subordinate clause) and *das* (in a separate sentence) work:

> Meine Großeltern starben beide im Alter von 80 Jahren, was für Indonesier schon ziemlich viel ist.
> Meine Großeltern starben beide im Alter von 80 Jahren. Das ist für Indonesier schon ziemlich viel.

The 2nd is the direct analogue to English

> My grandparents both died at the age of 80. That is already a pretty good deal for Indonesians.

---

Tentative answer why *welches* (nor *das* in a subordinate clause construction) doesn't work as well as *was* here, based mostly on oddity to the native ear: I tend to think that *welches* would be too narrow in that it refers to Alter only, whereas *was* (or *das*) refers to the whole situation. (?)

---

If you look at the [example section for which in wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/which#Pronoun), the which here is like example no. 3 for the relative which, *which* would also be translated as *was* in German. (= *was* im Deutschen auch mit *was* übersetzt [werden] würde.)

> He walked by a door with a sign, which read: PRIVATE OFFICE.
> *-> welches/das; ignoring that signs don't read in German*

> A situation in which tensions are high.
> *-> in welcher/in der*

> **He had to leave, which was very difficult.
>
> *-> was/das + taking the sentence apart***

> No art can be properly understood apart from the culture of which it is a part.
> *-> derer/[von welcher]; rather different construction*

An alternative that works both in German and English is that you can make two sentences with *that*/*das*:

> My grandparents both died at the age of 80. *That* is already a is already a pretty good deal for Indonesians.
>  Meine beiden Großeltern starben im Alter von 80 Jahren. *Das* ist für Indonesier schon ziemlich viel.

I tend to think that this covers the whole "which is"-ing. The construction with ", was" is very common in German, so in that sense I'd say, yes, "which is"-ing is done in German very much like in English - only it translates to *was* and not like many other *which*es to *welche/r/s*.

* To me, trying *what* for this type of *which* sounds unusual but not entirely impossible. This may be an old link between English and German - or my lovely German accent in English grammar ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Meine beiden Großeltern starben im Alter von 80 Jahren, welche für Indonesier schon ziemlich viel ist.

Mit *Welches* statt *welche* (das Alter, welches/ die Katze, welche/ der Bär, welcher) fast perfekt. Bei Alter verwendet man nicht *viel*, sondern *hoch*.

> Meine beiden Großeltern starben im Alter von 80 Jahren, welches für Indonesier schon ziemlich hoch ist.

Wie andere schreiben ist *das* ähnlich, wenn nicht weiter verbreitet, als *welches*, aber nicht besser.

Auch gegen die Satzkonstruktion ist nichts einzuwenden. So sprechen und schreiben auch Muttersprachler.